# Break string into rows tab delimited SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am attempting to write a function which splits a string form a .txt file (tab delimited) bulk inserted into a SQL Server table.

I have successfully run the procedure (with function) on a comma-delimited result from the bulk insert but can't seem to get it to successfully split the string into rows for tab-delimited. The result returns the string as a single row!

Would be great if someone could help out.

Here is the code for the function

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.BreakStringIntoRows (@CommadelimitedString varchar(1000))
RETURNS @Result TABLE (Headers VARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IntLocation INT

    WHILE (CHARINDEX('\t', @CommadelimitedString, 0) > 0)
    BEGIN
          SET @IntLocation = CHARINDEX('\t', @CommadelimitedString, 0)      

          INSERT INTO @Result (Headers)
             --LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed
             SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CommadelimitedString, 0, @IntLocation)))   

          SET @CommadelimitedString = STUFF(@CommadelimitedString, 1, @IntLocation, '') 
    END

    INSERT INTO @Result (Headers)
       SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(@CommadelimitedString))  -- LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Comment: The problem is the splitter. You need a new one because this one is horrible inefficient. Here is an excellent article with a number of splitters that are a lot more efficient. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Once you have a new splitter you need to pass the ASCII character instead of \t

Comment: `\t` in SQL Server does not escape to `tab`, you need to actually use a tab, or probably more clearly `CHAR(9)`, so you might end up with `SET @IntLocation = CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), @CommadelimitedString, 0)`

Comment: For SQL Server 2014+, look at the [`BULK INSERT` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). For other versions, look at the [bcp.exe utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or the SQL Server Integration Services. In any case, **do not roll your own CSV parser**.

Comment: @GarethD should post the answer below as an answer, so NClelland can accept the answer and close this one.

Comment: @GarethD this is now working with your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

\t in SQL Server does not escape to tab, you need to actually use a tab, or probably more clearly CHAR(9), so you might end up with SET @IntLocation = CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), @CommadelimitedString, 0) – GarethD